# Why does py2exe remove `help` and `license`?

Tags: python, packaging, py2exe

I packaged my Python app with py2exe. My app is a wxPython GUI, in which there is an interactive Python shell.

I noticed that I can't do `help(whatever)` in the shell. I investigated a bit and discovered that after the py2exe process, 3 items were missing from `__builtin__`. These are `help`, `license`, and another one I haven't discovered.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it? I want the users of my program to be able to use the `help` function of Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Reason:* These are added by the **site** module. I believe that py2exe doesn't package that.

*Fix:* Either explicitly `import site` or reimplement `help` (trivial).

See also: http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module